# Using Arduino timers

Tags: arduino, atmega, pwm

I am using this Arduino code to generate a 5V, 200 KHz pulse with 50% pulse-width.

```c
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  pinMode(pwmpin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(FBo, INPUT);
  pinMode(FBi, INPUT);
  noInterrupts(); // disable all interrupts 
  TCCR0A = 0;
  TCCR0B = 0;
  TCNT0  = 0;
  OCR0A = 40; // compare match register Duty Cycle *   16MHz/200kHz
  OCR0B = 40; // compare match register 1 - Duty Cycle * 16MHz/200kHz
  TIMSK0 |= (1 << OCIE0A); // enable timer compare interrupt
  digitalWrite(pwmpin,HIGH);
  TCCR0B |= (1 << CS00);
  interrupts(); // enable all interrupts
}

ISR(TIMER0_COMPA_vect) {
  digitalWrite(pwmpin, digitalRead(pwmpin) ^ 1);
  //TIMSK0 |= (1 << OCIE0B);  // enable timer compare interrupt
  //TIMSK0 &= ~(1 << OCIE0A);  // disable timer compare interrupt
}
```

Instead of a 5V 200 KHz pulse, it is showing me approximately a 2V 30 KHz signal. Can anyone tell me what the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are operating Timer/Counter0 in normal mode instead of CTC mode.

Try adding

```
TCCR0A |=  (1 << WGM01);
```

to your setup routine to enable counter reset on compare match.

---

Normal mode lets the timer count from `BOTTOM` (0) to `MAX` (255) regardless of what value you set `OCR0A` to. This will trigger an interrupt every 256 clock cycles (62.5 kHz with a clock frequency of 16 MHz). Your ISR needs to toggle the output pin twice to perform one full PWM cycle yielding the observed PWM frequency of round about 30 kHz.

From the [ATmega datasheet](http://www.atmel.com/images/Atmel-8271-8-bit-AVR-Microcontroller-ATmega48A-48PA-88A-88PA-168A-168PA-328-328P_datasheet_Complete.pdf):

> **15.7.1 Normal Mode**
>
> [...] In this mode the counting direction is always up (incrementing), and no counter clear is performed. The counter simply overruns when it passes its maximum 8-bit value (TOP = 0xFF) and then restarts from the bottom (0x00).

and

> **15.7.2 Clear Timer on Compare Match (CTC) Mode**
>
> In Clear Timer on Compare or CTC mode (WGM02:0 = 2), the OCR0A Register is used to manipulate the counter resolution. In CTC mode the counter is cleared to zero when the counter value (TCNT0) matches the OCR0A. [...]

For the 2V, my guess is you're measuring mean voltage (4.?V @ 50% duty cycle) instead of PWM peak voltage.

Comment: Thank You for your help.